# How to design shopping basket using session?

Tags: django, database-design, shopping-cart

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I'am newbie to Django. How to design shopping basket using session? (ask for a general "algorithm" or some example code)

Comment: Are you asking about DB design or something else? Also you could take some ideas from here https://github.com/ahmet/django-cart

Comment: I ask for db design and how to store product in session

Comment: You probably need to store the `cart` in session and not the product. The link I gave you features very simple code patterns. I suggest you take a look at it. Also, in order to design you DB, you have to make up your mind about the features you need. You question is quite vague at this point.

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't use a model. You can store the values directly in the session. Considering that you can store everything in the session you can store the items in a dictionary do something like.

```
def view_cart(request):
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    # rest of the view

def add_to_cart(request, item_id, quantity):
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[item_id] = quantity
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    # rest of the view
```